# Ringtone prints stacktraces for android 29

Tags: android

I've noticed that every time I use `Ringtone.play/stop` on android 29 it prints this stacktrace as level INFO:

```
2019-07-30 19:28:05.657 14498-14498/com.tinycorp.rise I/Ringtone: stop java.lang.Throwable
    at android.media.Ringtone.stop(Ringtone.java:458)
    at android.media.RingtoneManager.getRingtone(RingtoneManager.java:515)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.ringtone.AndroidRingtones.init(AndroidRingtones.kt:27)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.di.module.RingtoneModule.providesAndroidRingtones(RingtoneModule.java:36)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.di.module.RingtoneModule_ProvidesAndroidRingtonesFactory.proxyProvidesAndroidRingtones(RingtoneModule_ProvidesAndroidRingtonesFactory.java:52)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.di.module.RingtoneModule_ProvidesAndroidRingtonesFactory.provideInstance(RingtoneModule_ProvidesAndroidRingtonesFactory.java:37)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.di.module.RingtoneModule_ProvidesAndroidRingtonesFactory.get(RingtoneModule_ProvidesAndroidRingtonesFactory.java:30)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.di.module.RingtoneModule_ProvidesAndroidRingtonesFactory.get(RingtoneModule_ProvidesAndroidRingtonesFactory.java:11)
    at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.di.module.FragmentModule_ProvidesViewModelFactoryFactory.provideInstance(FragmentModule_ProvidesViewModelFactoryFactory.java:113)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.di.module.FragmentModule_ProvidesViewModelFactoryFactory.get(FragmentModule_ProvidesViewModelFactoryFactory.java:75)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.di.module.FragmentModule_ProvidesViewModelFactoryFactory.get(FragmentModule_ProvidesViewModelFactoryFactory.java:20)
    at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.di.component.DaggerAppComponent$FragmentComponentImpl.injectHomeFragment(DaggerAppComponent.java:380)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.di.component.DaggerAppComponent$FragmentComponentImpl.inject(DaggerAppComponent.java:357)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreate(HomeFragment.java:64)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:844)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1196)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:118)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1844)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1802)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1679)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:530)
    at com.tinycorp.rise.ui.home.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

If I run the same code on android 25, then none of the stacktraces appear...
Could this be an Android bug or am I doing something wrong on my end?